# Program to find the area of a circle in C

Tags: c

I'm a new learner to C and I have found this program which is to find the area of a circle. However my compiler keeps throwing this error at me:

[Error] C:\Users\Jiachenn\Documents\C-Free\Projects\HelloWorld\main.c:11: error: syntax error before "printf"

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
  int radius;
  float pi =3.14f, area;
  clrscr();
  printf("Input the radius:");
  scanf("%d",&radius);
  area = pi*radius*radius
  printf("\n Area of circle= %f", area);
  getch();
}
```

Do help!

Comment: count your semicolons.

Comment: `area = pi*radius*radius`------------------<< Check!!

Comment: area = pi * radius * radius;

Comment: You forgot a semicolon in the line before `printf`.

Comment: You missed a semicolon in the line beginning with area.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting._

Comment: Do not..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing the semicolon on the end of line

```
area = pi*radius*radius ;
```